# After a child process died, would all the pointers declared in the child be freed?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

As the title says, would all the pointers be freed after the child dies or do I have to free them manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

The OS is a good housekeeper and tidys up for you.

But being a good guest it is better to do it yourself.

Perhaps files need to be closed, network connections tidied up

Comment: Modern O/S are good housekeepers.  The earliest versions of AmigaOS, at least, did not clean up behind you.  If your program exited without freeing resources, those resources were not available until you rebooted the machine.  But we're talking ancient history here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - You are dating yourself (as the joke goes somebody has to)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it didn't even clean up after `malloc()`?  Why is the OS even involved in that?  Even in DOS it wouldn't have mattered.

Comment: Yup — I'm marginally more antique than AmigaOS. @AdrianRatnapala: I'm working from memory; the article on AmigaOS at Wikipedia doesn't confirm or deny my recollection.  And I'm strictly talking AmigaOS 1.0; I'd moved companies before even 1.1 came out, and never did anything with it again.  The Wikipedia article on [Amiga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga) does mention lack of memory protection in the section on Operating Systems, not explicitly stating what I say, but getting close to that.

Answer (score 1):

When a process dies, the kernel cleans up all the memory which process was using, unless it was shared with some other process.  This does not technically involve "freeing the pointers" in the sense of a call to `free()`, instead the kernel frees up the blocks of memory which the C library had used to implement `malloc()`.

**However** I like to make sure my programs always `free()` everything they `malloc()` (I check using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)) because this makes me more confident that the individual parts are not leaking memory.  That is especially important in long-running programs, but just seems like the "right thing" even in other programs.